# How do I us the trim function to reduce a URL to just the end page?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to take this URL

- https://info.example.edu/programs/degree/page-one/

and trim it down to

- page-one

by adjusting this formula

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",REPT(" ",100)),100))
```

Here are some things to consider:

- avoid using regex
- and, the amount of "/"s could change depending on
  the location of the page in the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try
=SUBSTITUTE(IF(LEN(A2)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))),1)>1,RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("@", SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))))), RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))-1)))), "/", "")

This accounts for a forward slash at the end of the URL or not.
Otherwise, if the formatting is always the same,
=SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))-1))), "/", "")

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "(.+)\/"), "[^/]+$")))
```

[image]

or:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(
 IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:A, "\/$"), A1:A, A1:A&"/"), "(.+)\/"), "[^/]+$")))
```

[image]